# How to convert array of images (from input field) into json string

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array of images created with

```
var a = Array.from(document.getElementById("id").files);
```

then I want to make a JSON string of that array with

```
var b = JSON.stringify(a);
```

but it produces nothing but an empty array. As I read this is a common problem with stringify but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: you are trying to implement stringify on img elements?

Comment: can you provide an example log of when you `console.log(a)` after creating the array?

Comment: are your images in  html canvas ??

Comment: here's log of console.log(a): https://imgur.com/B8SoaIQ

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array of images are proper [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) objects, they are a type of binary data called [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob).

JSON.Stringify won't work out of the box with blobs, but here is an answer with some workarounds: [JSON.stringify or how to serialize binary data as base64 encoded JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27232604/json-stringify-or-how-to-serialize-binary-data-as-base64-encoded-json)